# Why isn't Skype showing up in the systray after upgrading to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, indicator, skype

I have tried allowing Skype to show up in the systray by running:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'scp-dbus-service', 'Update-notifier', 'Skype']"
```

I also attempted to do:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

Both of the times I restarted Skype afterwards. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved itself for me for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this problem on my laptop, and my solution was to simply reinstall Skype (i386) from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Thanks, yes, reinstalling Skype fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Skype now has an app-indicator in Ubuntu 11.10, so you don't need to whitelist it. Maybe removing Skype from the systray whitelist will get the indicator to kick in?